# MetaPost figures in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, previewing

I use org-mode to write reports and export them to LaTeX (and later to PDF). I am looking for a way to write MetaPost in the same file as the rest of the text, to preview them (preferably the same way I do with LaTeX formulae), and effortlessly export the whole buffer to LaTeX.

Is there an existing solution I am missing?

P.S.: I've seen ["Best way to include METAPOST in ConTeXt exporter" thread](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2021-10/msg00224.html), however, the suggested solution doesn't seem sound enough and doesn't support previewing.